# Value of using a 3rd party recruiter's candidates, for employer

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

Recently I was conducting a job search and working with a recruiter I know, who submits my resume+credentials to various companies we discuss.  Some of these companies are small, such that I'd never discover them on my own, and the recruiter is a useful connecting agent.   Other companies are larger, well known names that I could likely have gone to their website and applied quite easily.  They probably get enough interest as well that they aren't hurting for candidates.

For these well known companies, what is the value of the company working with recruiter referred candidates instead of just candidates without one?  I'm thinking that the recruiter candidate obviously comes with an extra initial cost to hire (upwards of 10-15% of a year's salary?), and thus the independents would be cheaper to review.

From my perspective, I wonder if going into an application with a recruiter becomes a hindrance, in that I'll need to be that much better a candidate to justify the extra expense.  Is this a fair assumption, or do company hiring budgets expect recruiter fees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my perspective, I wonder if going into an application with a
>   recruiter becomes a hindrance, in that I'll need to be that much
>   better a candidate to justify the extra expense. Is this a fair
>   assumption, or do company hiring budgets expect recruiter fees?

No. At least not in my years of experience as a hiring manager and working with recruiters.

Once the decision has been made to use a recruiter, I don't care if the best candidate comes from the paid recruiter, a referral from a friend, or walks in from the street. I just want to find a good candidate and get her/him hired quickly, so he/she can get up to speed and be productive.

The recruiting expense has already been justified and approved. Additionally, in the overall scheme of things, the cost of a recruiter is minimal compared to all the other costs associated with hiring and training an employee.